# where to put nw.js temp data -- `nw.App.dataPath + '/Cache'`?

Tags: filesystems, nw.js

I'm building a tool in nw.js.

The user can preview his creation, which opens a new nw.js window.

I would like to save temporary files somewhere for this preview.

Is the recommended place to save them in `nw.App.dataPath + '/Cache/[userPreview]'`, where `[userPreview]` is a name I make up?

Answer (score 1):

For versions `>= 0.13.x`, I've been saving user-specific files to the directory right above `nw.App.dataPath`. `nw.App.dataPath` returns the path in the user's profile folder, including the `Default` profile (from Chromium's point of view) folder. So, I've been stripping off the `Default` from the path and using that.

For versions `< 0.13.x`, I just use the equivalent of `nw.App.dataPath`, since Chromium at those versions doesn't include the new profile folder (`Default`, by default).

If you follow this convention, you might want to also create another folder in that location to help delineate that it is the `Preview` folder where all the preview files are located. For example (for version `>= 0.13.x`): `nw.App.dataPath.replace('/Default', '/Preview/[userPreview]')`.

I honestly don't know what the best practice is, but I hope that helps.